# Error:"Deployment failed because no Windows Phone 8 phone was detected. Make sure phone is connected and power on "

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, nokia

I installed VS 2012 Ultimate and Windows Phone 8 SDK. When I create new project of Windows Phone 8 app and direct when i am debugging, it will give me the error like : "Deployment failed because no Windows Phone 8 phone was detected. Make sure phone is connected and power on "

I also done registation and unlock my phone but till it will give Error.

I am using Nokia 710 phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be because you have Windows Phone 7 (7.5) on your Nokia 710?

> Deployment failed because no **Windows Phone 8** phone was detected. Make sure phone is connected and power on

Comment: :but i update my nokia lumia 7.0 to 8.0 now i dont know nokia lumia 710 is upgradable or not?

Comment: :When i update my phone at that time my lumia 710 screen is change in to windows 8 so it think windows 8 os is install but when i run application through vs 2012 than its give error....so its proble is nokia lumiya 710? or anything else?

Comment: Are you sure? As I know last available upgrade for your phone is upgrade to WP 7.8. You can check out OS version in `Settings -> About -> Software Version`

Comment: Nokia Lumia 710 is a WP7 device (uses Windows Phone 7.x OS), not WP8! So all you can deploy to it are WP7.x apps. And make sure that you have Zune installed as it is required by Visual Studio to deploy apps to the phone.

Comment: @Pedro Lamas:thanks for replay its not possible to install wp8 in my nokia Lumia 710 than Run wp8 application?...Actully i done like that but not working